# Database help/query

Tags: php, mysql

I was just wondering if I could do a php code with a database that goes like this: `(ID, username, full name, channel, link, email, skype)`. I want the database to have everyones data but in the php code I would like it to only echo the data of the `username`. Im not sure if it makes to much sense but for example if my `username` is `x` and there are 3 different recruiters `x`,`y`, and `z` with a total of 10 data for the database, I only want the data created by `x` to show because the `username = x`.

Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I don't try to confuse anyone. So if you can't understand feel free to post below and I will happily answer your questions as best as I can. If you can't be bothered no problem. Thanks for the time guys.

Comment: So, you want to `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE username = 'x'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's simple `SELECT` statement:

```
$db = new PDO(
    $config['connectionString'],
    $config['username'],
    $config['password']
);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users_table` WHERE `username` = :user');
$query->execute([':user' => "Slayer5000"]);
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

**UPDATE WITH YOUR CODE**

```
<?php
$db = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=goaerox_lkdb1",
    "goaerox_lkdb1",
    "njimkolp"
);

$query = $db->prepare('SELECT `id`, `channel`, `email`, `paypal`, `network`, `name` FROM `partners` WHERE `name` = :user');
$query->execute([':user' => $your_user_name_to_search_for]);
$user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>ID</td><td>Username</td><td>Full Name</td><td>Channel</td><td>Link</td><td>Email</td><td>Skype</td></tr>";

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$user->id}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$user->name}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$user->name} &lt;{$user->}&gt;</td>"; // Have no idea how you generate fullName here
    echo "<td>{$user->channel}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$user->paypal}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$user->email}</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: I will test it now and if it works I will accept the answer, thanks very much for the quick response.

Comment: Can you help me if this is the code?:
http://pastebin.com/Jr8GPm2Z

Comment: @GoAerox updated your code in link with PDO usage.

Comment: By the way how did you find the dashboard username and password?

Comment: @GoAerox You have included that information inside your posted code, so i just used it